# What is the difference between an adjudication and a proceeding?

Tags: canada, definition

What is the difference between an adjudication and a proceeding? Are they simply synonymous?

Comment: Please merge this with your nearly identical question http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4846/can-an-adjudication-on-an-issue-between-or-among-parties-be-considered-an-order